# window.scrollTo(0,0) does not work in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

I want to use

```
window.scrollTo(0,0)
```

to navigate to the top of a page after navigating. This doesn't work in iOS Safari . What is the best way to have the window scroll to the top of the page when navigating in Safari on an iOS device.

Comment: With these types of questions there should always be system and software version number specified and more detailed info how to reproduce such issue.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It works as expected on iOS 8, which is just released yesterday

Comment: This is not a very good answer, while Apple adoption of new OS systems is high, it is not 100%.